# uk airport trasit with or without visa?

Tags: transit

I am a Pakistani passeport holder living in France since 1974 on a resident card.I have to  travel from lyon(france) to Islamabad (pakistan) by British Airways with change of terminal and plane at Heathrow and Doha Airports.Do I need a transit visa in UK or Qatar?

Comment: Are all flights on a single ticket or are they booked separately?

Comment: Even though [technically you don't need a visa for UK transit](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/pakistan/transit/somewhere_else/no) because you have an EEA residence permit from France, I think the airline (especially low-coster) is likely to deny you boarding because they wouldn't believe this story: TWOV (transit without a visa) exemptions are rarely understood or listed. And airline's internal policies take priority over any website you can provide.

Comment: @yeputons TWOV exemptions are available to airlines on Timatic. Also available on IATA

Comment: @Traveller Interesting, I was not able to find any mentions via public interfaces such as [Emirates' website](https://www.emirates.com/ae/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=in&residency=fr&destination=us&transit=gb), and I've also heard a bunch of stories with denied boarding in the recent years. Good to know it's at least somewhere.

Comment: @yeputons IATA is a public interface https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/